# I have scroller bar is not working properly

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar

I have a comment section on my page, And I add a scroller for comments. If in the comments section there are no comments then I want to hide the scroller bar. In my CSS I give   `overflow: auto;` but still it shows scroller bar when there are no comments.

CSS:

```
<style>
    .scrollbar
             {
                margin-left: 30px;
                float: left;
                height: 300px;
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 25px;
                overflow: auto;
             }

             .force-overflow
             {
                min-height: 450px;
             }
             #style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-track
             {
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                 background-color: #F5F5F5;
             }
             #style-6::-webkit-scrollbar
             {
                width: 10px;
                background-color: #F5F5F5;
             }

             #style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
             {
                background-color: #F90; 
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,
                rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
                transparent 25%,
                transparent 50%,
                rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
                rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
                transparent 75%,
                transparent)
              }
</style>
```

Code:

```
<div class="scrollbar" id="style-6">
               <div style=" height:270px;" class="force-overflow">
                  <?php foreach ($userComments as $comment):?> 
                  <div class="post-details-wrapper">
                     <?php 
                        $postdate =strtotime($comment['timestamp']);
                        $now = time();
                        ?>
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <p>
                           <img style="height: 45px;width: 48px;border-radius:50%;" src="<?php echo base_url();echo $comment['thumb_url']?>" />
                           &nbsp;
                           <b style="padding-right:6px;padding-left:6px;border-radius:25px;background-color:#888888;color:white;font-family:Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:500;>"><?php echo $comment['username'];?></b>
                           &nbsp;<?php echo date('d-m-Y',$postdate);?>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <p style="font-size:15px;"><?php echo $comment['comment']?></p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
               </div>
             </div>
```

In the bellow image, you can see the scroller bar present when no comments.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set: `overflow-y:auto;` instead of `overflow:auto;`
Maybe it will help

Comment: Try changing min-height in your .force-overflow class. It is set to 450px which is more than 300px in your .scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

make scroll bar height to min-height: 300px . It may help.

```
.scrollbar
         {
            margin-left: 30px;
            float: left;
            min-height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            overflow: auto;
         }
```

Comment: It hides the `scroller` bar but when I show my all comments still it hides `scroller` bar